# C++ quaternion chaos warping glitch

Tags: 3d, quaternions

I am making a "retro" 3D engine for a flight simulator and I implemented  quaternions to avoid gimbal lock, but if the angle is big the vertices start to make weird things, and by big i mean 0.05f xD , If the angle is enough  small the model rotates but there is a litle displacement that I can see when I do a triangle rasterization. This problem does not occur when I do rotation with common 4x4 matrices( using euler angles ), but obviously gimbal lock arrives...

[image]

```
Quaternion Mesh::YawRotation (vec3D Axis) 

{

    Quaternion q;

    q.x = Axis.x * sinf( aYaw / 2 );

    q.y = Axis.y * sinf( aYaw / 2 );

    q.z = Axis.z * sinf( aYaw / 2 );

    q.w = cosf( aYaw / 2 );

    q.Normalize();

    return q;

}

Quaternion Mesh::PitchRotation (vec3D Axis) 

{

    Quaternion q;

    q.x = Axis.x * sinf( aPitch / 2 );

    q.y = Axis.y * sinf( aPitch / 2 );

    q.z = Axis.z * sinf( aPitch / 2 );

    q.w = cosf( aPitch / 2 );

    q.Normalize();

    return q;

}

Quaternion Mesh::RollRotation (vec3D Axis)

{

    Quaternion q;

    q.x = Axis.x * sinf( aRoll / 2 );

    q.y = Axis.y * sinf( aRoll / 2 );

    q.z = Axis.z * sinf( aRoll / 2 );

    q.w = cosf( aRoll / 2 );

    q.Normalize();

    return q;

}

void Mesh::Rotate(vec3D &v) 
{

    //Axis//
    vec3D x = left;
    vec3D y = Up;
    vec3D z = forward;

    //quat = permanent quaternion or current orientation//
    //Current Quaternion//
    Quaternion Yaw;
    Quaternion Pitch;
    Quaternion Roll;

    if(ApplyPitchquatp || ApplyPitchquatn) 
    {
        Pitch = PitchRotation(x);
        quat.Normalize(); Pitch.Normalize();
        quat = quat * Pitch;
        quat.Normalize();
    }
    if(ApplyYawquatp || ApplyYawquatn) 
    {
        Yaw = YawRotation(y);
        quat.Normalize(); Yaw.Normalize();
        quat  = quat * Yaw;
        quat.Normalize();
    }
    if(ApplyRollquatn || ApplyRollquatp) 
    {
        Roll = RollRotation(z);
        quat.Normalize(); Roll.Normalize();
        quat  = quat * Roll;
        quat.Normalize();
    }

    //Transform quat to matrix//
    Matrix trans = quat.GetMatrix();
    vec4D vert(v);
    vert = vert.MulMatrix( trans );
    v = vert.ToVec3();

}
```

The problem becomes more chaotic when angle increases